# Windows key / icon doesn't work

Tags: windows-10

By that I mean that pressing the windows key does not show the menu. [keycode.info](http://keycode.info/) shows the key being pressed. Typing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> outputs x here instead of showing a menu. Clicking on the windows icon does nothing. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> does nothing. Any idea why?

**Also, clicking the windows button does nothing.**

I have tried restarting `explorer.exe`, spamming the windows key and yelling **I HATE YOU MICROSOFT** as loud as I could, but it didn't work.

If it helps, pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> shows this:

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use System File Checker (SFC) to find and replace corrupt system files

1. Open Task Manager by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>
2. Select File (menu), Run new task (item)
3. Type `powershell`, check "Create this task with administrative privileges.", and click OK.
4. Type `sfc /scannow` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. If SFC was unable to fix some files, run the following and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>: 
   `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`

Read the article below for further steps.

Source: [How to fix your Windows 10 Start Menu - BT](http://home.bt.com/tech-gadgets/computing/has-your-windows-10-start-menu-stopped-working-here-are-four-ways-to-fix-it-11364000314532)